# Laravel authentication redirect error

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am new to Laravel so please excuse my ignorance. I am going through the beginner tutorials and have gotten stuck on the built in authentication system...

I have created a new app and followed the docs on setting up authentication, I searched through stack overflow and overcame one issue (I had to put the auth routes in the middleware group), however now no matter what I do it redirects to the root "/" path...even when I manually go to auth/logout and then auth/login...can someone please help?

Comment: This situation is similar to this question, but was not able to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575113/redirecting-user-from-login-page-to-home-page-if-authenticated-in-laravel

Comment: You need to show some code. What do your routes look like? No code = guesswork by everybody.

Comment: you put the auth routes in what middleware group?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.2 after running their standard

`> php artisan make:auth`

let's assume we want to ensure user authentication when going to `/admin` route.

In the `routes.php` there will be an entry like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function() {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
    Route::get('/admin', [
        'as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index'
    ]);        
});
```

and in `AuthController.php` an additional method must be added:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function authenticated()
    {
        return redirect()->intended();
    }    
}
```

As a result every time when unauthenticated user tries to access `/admin` URL it will be redirected to some `/login` page and if authentication succeeds he will be able to access `/admin` page.

A few points to notice in the code above:

- both `web` and `auth` middleware groups are required (`auth` without `web` won't have session support and as a result `url.intended` is not saved in the session and the whole redirect mechanism does not work)
- the method name in AuthController is `authenticated` and not `authenticate` mentioned in Laravel documentation (it's called once authentication is verified)

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood, your routes should look like this.

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

and you should have at the very least the login.blade.php template in your Auth folder (in views).

If you truly are going to start again, consider deleting the question as it doesn't really help anyone in it's current state.

---

Try this in your Auth controller

```
    public function authenticated( $request,  $user ) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath().'?success');
    }
```

Comment: Actually... What is your problem exactly? The after authentication redirect? Or the posting of the form, as in... Does your form submit to the Auth/login (form action)?

Comment: Thaks, I added that function to my auth controller, it did not seem to be working so I thought it might be my browser, I first used Chrome in incognito mode and it worked and then tried Firefox and it also worked, any idea why it is acting strange in Chrome?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is the PHP file not having been fully saved. Are you saying it doesn't work in normal chrome though? Cause a redirect, regardless should be working cross-browser. Please test it again, I have this code running on several production sites and has never caused me any trouble.

Comment: Sorry that was preemptive, it is still not working..even when I manually go to the auth/login page it redirects to the root page and displays the welcome view...I am going to completely start over later tonight. The session files are being created in storage/framework/sessions so it appears to be working up to the redirect portion...