# Laravel authentication redirect fails

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, redirect

Followed this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqkt6eSsRZs&list=PL_UnIDIwT95NUvLU14l_QFFV2ZxO1phpQ&index=10

Added auth routes from laravel docs

```
mkdir auth
chmod -R 777 auth
```

Created login/register views

Created /home route

Customized AuthController:

```
protected $redirectTo = 'home';
protected $redirectPath = 'home';
protected $loginPath = '/auth/login';
```

When attempting to access auth/login I got this error:

> ErrorException in Request.php line 775: .. Session store not set on
>       request.

Moved auth routes to middleware group.

Successfully registered, created user in db and sessions file

Changed home route to check is user is logged in:

```
if(Auth::guest()) {
    return Redirect::to('auth/login');
} else {
    echo "welcome home";
}
```

Went to auth/logout and then back to home route, was not redirected to login page but to root of site
Now whenever I go to auth/login it also redirect me to the root path, so I went to incognito mode and went to the auth/login page, it rendered successfully and logged me in (created a session file in storage/framework/sessions) but then also redirected me to the root path.

From a previous answer I then added this to my auth controller:

```
public function authenticated( $request,  $user ) {
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath().'?success');
}
```

Problem still exists when going to home route in normal mode (Chrome) but redirects to auth/login page in incognito mode, and creates session file but still redirects to root path after successful login. I then commented out the authenticated() method in the auth controller but problem still exists...

Previous question: [Laravel authentication redirect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501062/laravel-authentication-redirect-error)

Comment: First, please format your question properly

Comment: are you attaching auth middleware to your route?

Comment: no I am not attaching the auth middleware, I am simply following that tutorial on getting basic authentication working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Laravel 5.2 version then you will need to use web middleware, in my case I have this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
   Route::auth();
   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Where as for version Laravel version 5 and 5.1 you need to have this below routes:

```
Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, I am running Laravel 5.2 so I added that to my routes file, and it works in Firefox but in Chrome always redirects to the root path (even after going to auth/logout), so I will be doing my testing in Firefox. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: I AM SO sorry...I thought I was using 5.1 but turns out I am using 5.2...again so sorry!